# adjust battery-warning-level of magic mouse

Tags: battery, settings, mouse

How can I adjust the level at which Mac OS warns me about the battery of my magic mouse?
I always have a lack of batteries, so I would prefer if the battery warning comes up at 15 or 20%, so I could work the rest of the day with the almost empty batteries and put them in the charger before I go to sleep.

Right now, if the warning occurs in the morning I have a problem.
I tried to steal the batteries out of my girlfriends camera or her wireless keyboard, but she does karate and defends her batteries.
Buying another set is not an option.

A way to get the battery level via applescript, shellscript, automator, whatever would be applicable too.

Comment: Invest in rechargeable AA's! Saves you money in the long run *and* it's much better for the earth!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [thread](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114395) has some scripts that can help you.

It seems that you wrap the results of this shell snippet in a nice AppleScript:

```
ioreg -c BNBMouseDevice | grep BatteryPercent
```

Comment: The link no longer works. Do you have something more up to date?

Answer (score 3):

In my **macOS Sierra 10.12.6**, there is no `BNBMouseDevice`. Script which works for me is:

```
ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l | grep BatteryPercent | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'
```

Source: [Check the battery level of connected bluetooth headphones from the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293811/223548)