# Check the battery level of connected bluetooth headphones from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, battery, bluetooth

I am trying to check the battery level of my wireless headphones from the command line.  I came across a [few](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=3769) [discussions](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/18/how-to-check-bluetooth-keyboard-battery-levels-from-the-command-line-on-mac-os-x/), and it seems all I need to do is enter the following:

`ioreg -c 'deviceName' |grep -i batterypercent`

I tried this command using "Powerbeats Wireless" and "bluetoothaudiod" for the `'deviceName'`'s, but neither returned the `batterypercent`. I tried `ioreg -c bluetoothaudiod |grep -i battery` to get general information about the battery, and get this as a response:

```
| |   +-o AppleSmartBatteryManager  <class AppleSmartBatteryManager, id 0x100000250, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
| |     +-o AppleSmartBattery  <class AppleSmartBattery, id 0x100000252, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
```

If I connect the headphones to my **iPhone**, the battery level *immediately* pops up on the toolbar.  This leads me to believe that the device is broadcasting battery level, and that I should be able to access this information from my computer.

How can I check the battery level of my bluetooth connected headphones?

**Edit:**

Initially I thought the issue was with the device name, but it seems `"Powerbeats Wireless"` and `bluetoothaudiod` work interchangeably.  Just can't figure out how to access the `batterypercent` param.

**Edit 2:**

Looking at the Bluetooth docs, it seems there's a **Battery Service** which exposes the **Battery State** and **Battery Level**.  The Battery Level can be read using the ***GATT*** Read Characteristic Value sub-procedure, so I need to figure out a way of interfacing with this service from the command line. I have a feeling `batterypercent` may only be coded for standard peripherals (trackpad, mouse, keyboard), as all battery monitoring widgets I've tried are only compatible with such devices.

**Edit 3:**

Revisiting this almost a year later.  I know have a wireless trackpad & keyboard, and can see their battery levels perfectly fine ( in both the toolbar or the command line). Still unable to get the battery level from my headphones though, and not sure why :/

Comment: `ioreg -c "Powerbeats Wireless" |grep -i battery` also returns the general battery info, so i think i have the correct device name.  But why is the `batterylevel` command not working !! Smh

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting on your own question.

Comment: @IronCraftMan edits are now complete.  You think you could offer any help?

Comment: Hi - I'm interested in hearing if you got any further.  I want to get the battery life out of PS4 controllers connected by BlueTooth to my iMac.

Comment: Doesn't work for my JVC bluetooth headphones either. Strange, because my 5-year-old iPhone 4S has no problem telling me their battery level when connected.

Comment: Looks like some devices and Mac's don't play nice --- either BT hardware in the mac can't do it or (more likely) the mac software doesn't implement some versions of the standard. If we could access the BT hardware direct, perhaps there'd be hope? That's a bit out of scope today though ;-) Maybe this?: https://github.com/toy/blueutil

Answer (score 14):

On my iMac(macOS 10.12.6), none of solutions mentioned above works. After reading the man page of **ioreg**. The solution that works on my computer is:

```
// the -r option is used to reduce output
// the -l option is used to display properties for all object
// by default some object properties are not shown
// the -c specify device class, the class could be specific or general
ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l
ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l | grep -i battery

// instead of using device io class, you could also use a property key to query
// you need to know one of target device's property key(-k), for example it is BatteryPercent for Bluetooth keyboard and mouse
// any device with this property will be listed
ioreg -r -l -k "BatteryPercent"
ioreg -r -l -k "BatteryPercent" | grep -i battery
```

There are some other device classes to try for the -c argument: **AppleHSBluetoothDevice**  **AppleHSBluetoothHIDDriver** **AppleMultitouchMouseHIDEventDriver** **AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2**, they give different output.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers works for me.

This app works for me:

https://github.com/jariz/Akku/ (note: this tool is no longer being actively worked on and won't work in Monterrey or later)

It is open-source and free.

Remember to download version 0.1.0-beta.10.

[image]

Comment: Been looking for an app like this for a while. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Currently, notifications have a problem. Apart from that, I tested on 2 devices & it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Worked for me with JBL T460BT. Thanks.

Comment: Nice app, but didn't work with QC 35 II :( (no reported battery state...)

Comment: My headphones don't report battery status without it being explicitly requested, and this app doesn't request it. I had to connect my headphones to my phone as well so it can give out a report, and this app DID intercept it and show it.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `ioreg`. You'll need to know the name of the device. Just follow [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/18/how-to-check-bluetooth-keyboard-battery-levels-from-the-command-line-on-mac-os-x/) guide.

The guide, in short, basically has you run the `ioreg -c <devicename> |grep '"BatteryPercent" ='`

Example:

```
ioreg -c BeatsBluetoothHeadset |grep '"BatteryPercent" ='
```

[image]

Additionally, you could retrieve broader battery information with:

```
ioreg -c BeatsBluetoothHeadset |grep Battery
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! This problem seems to be specific to the Beats headphones, as I can access battery levels for my wireless keyboard & trackpad.  Will update the original question!

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: That guide isn't telling us how to find the name of the device.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that to check the battery level of my powerbeats 3 on my Mac I just go to the bluetooth menu in the icon area in the top right of the screen, hover over your connected powerbeats and then it shows the battery level right there. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm on MacOS 12.6 Monterey.  My bluetooth icon shows the power level of my Magic Mouse and Logitech Keyboard, but it will not show any of several brands of headset that I've used, perhaps because they are dongle-based and not true USB.

Answer (score 0):

This set of flags boils down the output to the minimum and the following code gives you just percentage as a number.

```
ioreg -r -n AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -k BatteryPercent | perl -nE '/"BatteryPercent" = (\d++)/ && say $1'
```

I use this with BetterTouchTool.