# Get low battery notifications for mouse earlier

Tags: battery, mouse

Is it possible to tweak the % that I get warning of low battery for my Magic Mouse 2?

I currently only get it at 2% at which point it's very close to dying so I have to stop what I'm doing and plug it in. A reminder about 10-15% would allow me to plug it in the next time I have a natural break.

Comment: 2%? You are lucky. Mine simple died with no warning at all!

Answer (score 37):

For those willing to copy and run a bash script and add a cron job, here is a complete solution that is free and current (as of macOS Catalina 10.15.3) and requires no programming (I've done that part for you), just a little system administration:

Save this to a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script like `~/.mouse-battery-check.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# current battery level
BATT=$(ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l \
  | grep -i mouse -A 20 | grep BatteryPercent | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2)

# defaults to warn at 20%; accepts other number as 1st argument (useful for testing)
COMPARE=${1:-20}

if [ -z "$BATT" ]; then
  echo 'No mouse found.'
  exit 0
fi

if (( $BATT < $COMPARE )); then
  osascript -e "display notification \"Mouse battery is at ${BATT}%.\" with title \" Mouse Battery Low\""
fi
```

Open up Terminal and make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.mouse-battery-check.sh
```

Now you can test that the script sends a desktop notification by running it when your BlueTooth mouse is connected (this tests for battery less than 101%, so it should always send a notification):

```
~/.mouse-battery-check.sh 101
```

To test again with the default setting (20%):

```
~/.mouse-battery-check.sh
```

When a BlueTooth mouse is not detected, the script will return, "No mouse found."

### Checking Automatically

Now to test periodically and notify you automatically, add a new [cron job](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/cron-job-crontab-how-to-examples.html):

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Add an entry like to check every 15 minutes:

```
*/15 * * * * cd ~ && bash ~/.mouse-battery-check.sh
```

(You can again pass the battery percentage as a parameter to the script here.)

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit the editor and save the cron job.

### Compatibility

This has been tested on:

- Catalina 10.15.3
- Mojave 10.14.6
- High Sierra 10.13.x in June 2018

### Acknowledgements

For battery check, this answer:

[adjust battery-warning-level of magic mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/adjust-battery-warning-level-of-magic-mouse#answer-296035)

For notification, this answer:

[How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel#answer-115373)

For cron jobs, this blog:

https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html

User sirclesam for compatibility testing.

### Enhancement - also check keyboard (and maybe trackpad)

I modified the script above to check both Apple Magic Mouse and Keyboard.  With the addition of one word it could check Trackpads, or any other overpriced Apple Magic doo dads, as well.  I only have the mouse and keyboard so I started with that.   I also changed the default to 10% which still gives me a few days to plug it in. Trackpad does follow the same syntax.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Check battery level of Apple Magic Mouse and Keyboard and Notify if low

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# Warn at 10% or according to first parameter.  Pass in 101 for testing.
COMPARE=${1:-10}

# Check each device.  
# If you have a Trackpad please add the suitable token to this list and test it.
for HIDThingy in Keyboard Mouse; do
    # Determine battery level of Apple Magic Thingy
    BATT=$(ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l \
         | grep -i $HIDThingy -A 20 | grep BatteryPercent | sed -e 's/.* //')

    if [ -z "$BATT" ]; then
      echo "No $HIDThingy found."
    elif (( $BATT < $COMPARE )); then
      osascript -e "display notification \"$HIDThingy battery is at ${BATT}%.\" with title \" $HIDThingy Battery\""
    fi
done
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me whereas I never got BTT to work, thanks a lot for the great answer. I'm not sure if I should make it the accepted answer just because it's a bit more involved than a straightforward setting adjustment or GUI solution.

Comment: Incidentally a similar approach should work for Magic Keyboard.

Comment: Verified this solution still works for Catalina 10.15.3.  Thanks Will!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the test results, @sirclesam. I suspect the first part most likely to break eventually would be the ioreg command or the piped commands that parse its output.

Comment: I modified the above script to check both mouse and keyboard, and it could check trackpad too with one very tiny change but I don't have one to test with.   What is the best place to post my modification?  Write and answer a new question?   Edit this answer and add it to the end?  It's too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: @jay613 that's a cool idea and a good question. Since it goes a little beyond the scope of the OP question, I think the write and answer a new question idea is a good choice. But if you post a suggested edit to my answer, I think I get a chance to review before it takes effect. You'd get +2 credit as an editor, vs. +10 per upvote if you wrote an answer. You _could_ just add an answer _here_; if so I'd appreciate a mention for my contribution (if any) but that's really up to you. ;) Cheers.

Comment: @WillCain I'll try adding to your answer.  Partly for experience, as I've never done that.  Mainly because you provide so much detail about the end to end process, my new question and answer would either have to copy (plagiarize?) most of it verbatim, or just be a partial answer (my code only) and refer people here for all the idiot-proof detail.

Comment: Verified works perfectly with macOS Big Sur, Thanks Will

Comment: The script wasn't working for me because of missing `$` in the `BATT < COMPARE` line. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

There is a way!

Sadly you need [BTT (Better Touch Tools)](https://www.boastr.net/) for this. BTT was free, but to support ongoing development there is now a pay-what-you-want license model starting at 5 USD. But afaik you can test it for free for some days.

How to set the notification:

1. Start BTT → Menu bar → Preferences → Basic Settings → Check "Launch BTT on startup"
2. Switch to Advanced settings (top left hand corner)
3. Go to Mouse settings (top right hand corner)
4. Under "General" at the bottom there is "Warn if battery level is lower than X %"
5. Check the option and set your level.

[image: btt screenshot]

Comment: Thanks just installed it now, seems like the app does a lot more that I can poke around with.

Comment: Yes, the app is for me a must have! Window snapping, custom keystroke commands and so much more!

Comment: If you have a Magic Trackpad, BTT is absolutely essential. I couldn't live without it these days.

Comment: ⚠️ In the current version of BetterTouchTool (4.157), I see this setting only for Magic Mouse, not for Normal Mouse. The UI is different now but `BetterTouchTool Settings ⇒ Advanced Settings ⇒ Magic Mouse` has the setting, while `BetterTouchTool Settings ⇒ Advanced Settings ⇒ Normal Mouse` does not.

Answer (score -1):

you can always download bitbar and just add some script to run, like this one https://github.com/kkunkel/OSX-Nagios.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and taking the time to post an answer!  It's helpful to *expand* on your answer to further explain/clarify what you are attempting to communicate.  It's also better to include the relevant points in this answer rather than just linking to another one.

Comment: **This checks computer battery not magic mouse battery.**