# Mouse battery warning percentage

Tags: battery, mouse

I use High Sierra on a MacBook Pro with a Magic Mouse. I rotate among three pairs of rechargeable batteries.

Today I got the warning about low mouse battery charge when the charge was at 9%. But the previous battery warned at 12% or 14%, I don't remember for sure (but I remember being surprised that it was more than 10%).

What criteria does MacOS use to decide when to warn about the mouse battery charge, since it's obviously not a fixed percentage?

Comment: Interesting. This does not answer your question, but it is possible to detect and warn about fixed or earlier (higher) battery percentages: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254703/get-low-battery-notifications-for-mouse-earlier/327627#327627

Comment: Thanks. I recently upgraded to MM2, which has USB charging instead of replacing batteries, so I'm not rotating among batteries any more.