# crontab doesn't seem to recognize `~`

Tags: command-line, cron

Has anybody noticed that `crontab` doesnt seem to recognize `~` to mean the home directory?

I tried using a full expansion of `/Users/username/filename.txt` in crontab, which worked, but using `~/filename.txt` results in failure.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 10):

The question proposed using `~/username/filename.txt` instead of `/Users/username/filename.txt`, but the proposed syntax should instead be either `~username/filename.txt` or `~/filename.txt`. For an illustration of a `crontab` entry which uses `~`, see the top rated answer to [Get low battery notifications for mouse earlier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254703/get-low-battery-notifications-for-mouse-earlier/327627#327627).

You can also test a simple example with this `crontab` entry:

```
* * * * * touch ~/NOT_A_FILE_I_CARE_ABOUT.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

`~` is a symbol *shells* automatically expand to `$HOME`, a standard `/bin/sh` (which `cron` uses to run the commands) does not need to support `~` expansion. The portable way is to use `$HOME` instead in your `crontab` file.

Answer (score -1):

Some shells support `~`, and some don't. Perhaps Apple uses `dash` as the default `cron` shell in Catalina, and `bash` in Monterey?; perhaps Apple changes the `cron` environment depending upon the phase of the moon?

Better than guessing what Apple has (or has not) done on some particular version of macOS, and on a machine that may or may not have user modifications... wouldn't it be better to run some simple tests - ask `cron` to tell you something about its environment? This would be an *objective truth*; one that requires no assumptions, and is not dependent upon *vagaries* in Apple's documentation.

Once a day (or whenever you wish), you can run a `cron` job that logs its environment and some other useful information from your system to a file. The file is always there, and its never more than 24 hours old (assuming your system was operating at the time you scheduled it).

A job similar to the one below in your `crontab` would answer your questions *"definitively"* (however see **NOTE 3.** below):

```
0 12 * * * (echo $(date); echo "What is '~'?:" ~; printenv) > /Users/seamus/mycronenv.txt 2>&1
```

This produces a file named `mycronenv.txt` in *my* $HOME directory that looks similar to this:

> Sat Jul 30 23:35:00 CDT 2022
> What is '~'?: /Users/seamus
> SHELL=/bin/sh
> MAILTO=
> USER=seamus
> PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
> PWD=/Users/seamus
> SHLVL=1
> HOME=/Users/seamus
> LOGNAME=seamus
> _=/usr/bin/printenv

As you can see, my system's (Catalina) `cron` recognizes `~` as $HOME. To verify this, I added another job to my `crontab` (see **NOTE 1.** below):

```
* * * * * (echo "Write this line to the file ~/testdir/testfile with a timestamp: "; echo $(date)) >> ~/testdir/testfile.txt 2>&1
```

Which worked as expected, writing the result to `$HOME/testdir/testfile.txt`.

And since I used the append form of the redirect (`>>`), it adds a new entry every minute - i.e. remove this job after your test!

Hope this helps clear the confusion - please let us know if the issue persists, or you have other questions.

---

###### NOTES:

1. If you want to try this on your machine, create the directory `testdir` first:

   ```shell
   % cd
   % mkdir testdir
   ```
2. On my system (Catalina), Apple has set the default configuration to send mail to me with a note re my `cron` job - which is not something I want. Consequently, I have added a line to my `crontab` to disable that:

   ```
   MAILTO=""
   ```
3. Wrt **definitively**:

   From `man sh` it seems that, rather than being **definitive**, Apple has given themselves some latitude: `cron` may use any one of three shells (`bash`, `dash` or `zsh`) in service of `/bin/sh`:

   > sh is a POSIX-compliant command interpreter (shell).  It is implemented by re-execing as either bash(1), dash(1), or zsh(1) as determined by the symbolic link located at /private/var/select/sh.  If /private/var/select/sh does not exist or does not point to a valid shell, sh will use one of the supported shells.

Comment: Wow.  So much here based on speculation.  Let’s start here:  the default shell for `cron` is `/bin/sh` unless otherwise specified by the she bang in the script.  Environment variables aren’t typically set so any tilde expansion (`~`) will result in access the home directory of the user that the cron job is executed under.

Comment: @Allan: ?! The primary point is **not to speculate**. If you had read the answer instead of looking for excuses to downvote, you might have picked up on that.

Comment: I never down voted.  That said, your second sentence re: `dash` starts it all off.  A quick reading of the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html)  would tell you the default shell for cron is `/bin/sh` if `SHELL` isn’t set.  Your `SHELL` is set to the default making it redundant.   The `~` falls under parameter expansion for Bourne (sh), Bourne Again (Bash) and Zsh.  I can’t speak to dash.

Comment: @Allan: I apologize if I made an error in deducing you were the downvoter; it's apparently a coincidence getting a comment and a downvote on the same day ~ 1 year after posting. But wrt the second sentence, the quote is verbatim from `man sh`, and it seems definitive to me. IOW, while `/bin/sh` *might be* the default for `cron`, `man sh` tells us that another shell may in fact be executed instead - depending upon the various settings. Also, I tend to rely upon the *local* man pages instead of third-party versions. Again, the point of my answer was to ***avoid speculation***.

Comment: No worries… I get accused of downvoting because I prefer to leave feedback.  But, to make this short, what you’re referencing isn’t accurate.  `cron` → `/bin/sh`.  That’s a given.  However, `/bin/sh` → anything else *if and only if* it doesn’t exist.  There’s no latitude for Apple there (as you put it). That’s also not an Apple thing, but the devs of the Bourne Shell - it’s that way across all platforms.

Comment: @Allan: You're arguing the point with the wrong person, Allan. The ***Apple man page*** says otherwise. No point debating it.

Comment: You’re reading the wrong man page. Read the one for `cron`

Comment: @Allan: Sorry, but you're mistaken: `man cron` does not mention ***any*** shell at all. I can see why you're confused on this.

Comment: My bad.  [man crontab](https://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html). Look under “Crontab comments and variables”

Comment: @Allan: You ***read*** `man 5 crontab`, but failed to consider the material in `man sh`;  `man sh`, as I mentioned in a previous comment, **still**determines how `bin/sh` is executed - depending on the various settings mentioned there. And in my ***Apple-sourced local `man 5 crontab`***, there is no `"Crontab comments and variables"`section; *are you using the 3rd party manuals again?* This is neither difficult, nor controversial. Given Apple's penchant for changing these settings, I feel it's more ***reliable*** to ask `cron` to tell you what shell you're using; i.e. "avoid speculation".

Comment: Go back to the 3rd comment.  I already addressed everything you brought up, now you’re questioning the veracity of the man page.  This is getting pedantic.

Comment: @Allan: Pedantic indeed... Refer to the 4th comment re `man sh`. Note reference to the file: `/private/var/select/sh`. If you check your Ventura 13.4 system, you may find that `bin/bash` is actually used instead of `/bin/sh` via a "soft link". Likewise for Catalina. And yes - I do contest the veracity of your 3rd party man page if it is not published by Apple (AFAIK **it is not**).